# PotPlayer playlist Issue

Tags: video, playlists, daum-pot-player

Whenever I play a video in Potplayer, it automatically creates a playlist from all the video files present in the same Folder. That's fine with me, but problem is it **always plays the last Video** in the playlist. Even when I select another file to play, it automatically travels through the list and again plays the Last Video.

How to solve this?

Have attached 2 screenshots for reference. I play the 2nd video, but still it plays the last one.

P.S- I know how to disable the playlist, but I don't want to.

[Screenshot_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRMsv.png)
[Screenshot_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLJ3N.png)

Comment: Do the previous files exist? Have you reached out to Pot Player support?

Comment: Yes, files are not disturbed in anyway. Regarding support, I haven't tried reaching them so far. But will do so now

Comment: I reached out to their Support, they also are not sure how to deal with this.

Comment: I can confirm this problem as I suffer from the same one (all files from one folder are automatically opened), although in my case PotPlayer does not jump to the last playlist entry.

Answer (score 1):

You mention 2 problems:

1. *"Whenever I play a video in Potplayer, it automatically creates a playlist from all the video files present in the same Folder."*
2. *"PotPlayer always plays the last Video in the playlist."*

**solutions:**

1. For your first problem go to (both):

   - `preferences (F5)` > `general` > `general settings` > `When files opened` > select `add only selected files to playlist`
   - `preferences (F5)` > `playback` > `playlists` > deselect `auto add similar files in play folder`
2. For your second problem: You say *"Even when I select another file to play, it automatically travels through the list and again plays the Last Video"*. If PotPlayer really travels through the list i.e. you can see the cursor move from file to file until reaching the end in an attempt to play these items (as opposed to starting right at the last item immediately), I can only imagine that these other files are not playable (because why else would they not play?). The possible reasons for this are too manifold to enumerate here, but could be one of the following:

   - files from an inaccessible network location
   - files from a USB drive which has changed drive letter
   - unknown codec
   - etc.

   Without further information this second problem is hard to diagnose from afar.